# Setting Background from Image on Android

Tags: java, android

So I have a program, this I want this program to change the background on the linear layout to a new image in the person's gallery every n minutes. Currently I am getting the path using the following...

```
public String getCurrentImageLocation(){
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor c = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    Integer test2 = c.getCount();
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    Integer randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(test2.intValue());
    c.moveToPosition(randomNumber);
    int rowId = c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    return c.getString(rowId);
}
```

At the risk of sounding super noob, how do I get this path and turn it into a drawable that I can use for setBackgrounDrawable(Drawable d). Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass the path to [createFromPath(String path)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#createFromPath%28java.lang.String%29). This should give you back a drawable resource you can use.

Comment: Yeah I saw that and tried it but apparently the .DATA doesn't give me a path like I thought. Any idea how I get that?

Comment: What path does the data column come back with? I have used the data column for audio files in the past and it works as a path to the file.

Comment: Problem was related to how a service starts up doesn't seem to start the service until after onCreate. For example if I use just view.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(backgroundImageService.getCurrentImageLocation())); it fails but if I set a listener on a button and try that way it works

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is by using

```
.setBackgroundBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path));
```